# Magento 1.9 custom option update price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options, custom

When selecting a custom options on the productpage, that increases the price. The default price on the page auto updates and increases.

But I display the price of the product on the productpage on 2 places. The default place and a custom place, on the buttom of the page.

The only problem is that the price on the bottom is not updated automatically when selecting the option. I load the price by the same way as the default page.

How can I auto update this price also?

Custom code:

```
<section id="options">
    <div class="product-accessoires product-options">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="product-options-block col-md-9 col-sm-9"> 
            </div>
            <div class="product-options-sidebar col-md-3 col-sm-3"> 
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is your frontend based on the default RWD? In that case Magento would include a price clone in the bottom wrapper already (hidden by css).

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner Thanks for your reply. No we use a custom theme, but if that is a default code, how can we include it in our custom view.phtml file?

Comment: @HenkZ take a reference of RWD theme, you will do this easily.